# Avoiding Duplicate function names in WordPress Post Loop (WP_Footer script)

Tags: php, wordpress

Say I created a plugin that injects content (used as a shortcode) into a post. I'm trying to push that code for each post to the bottom of the page.

This works fine, however when you are on an archive page with multiple posts using the same shortcode, there is an obvious conflict because the function names become duplicate and it will only output the footer code (activate_flex_slider) once.

```
<?php
function your_function() {
    echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');
?>
```

What i'm trying to do is output footer script so that there are multiple jQuery instances pointing to their respective ID's...

```
<?php
    function flex_slider() {
        $output ='<ul class="flexslider"><li>Slide Content</li></ul>';
        return $output;
    }


    function activate_flex_slider(){
        ?>
    <script>
                ( function ($) {
             $(window).load(function(){

       //different number will be prepended to ID (matches post ID #)
      $('#carousel-<?php echo $post->ID ?>').flexslider();
    });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
<?php
    }

    // Hook into footer so slider becomes active after page loads
    add_action('wp_footer','activate_flex_slider');

    // Create the Shortcode
    add_shortcode('flex_slider', 'flex_slider');
    ?>
```

Comment: I don't really have the full picture as to why the shortcode content needs to be inserted at the base of the page, but it seems to me like this could be solved with some creative CSS rather than PHP hackery.

Comment: i've edited my post to be more specific, as I think the original was not clear enough.

Comment: I turned my comment into the post below.

Answer (score 1):

So the entire issue here is caused my the consecutive hook queuing. What if we compiled all of the post id's and include your own javascript handler to dish out the flex_slider instances on page load. Just have the script enqueue only if the page is an archive page. If you make all of your carousel containers have a class unique to themselves then you can do something like this.

Put this in your page template or footer or header, it doesn't really matter where (of course fill in the generic things with your own):

```
 <?php if (is_archive()) wp_enqueue_script('special_sauce', '/js/special_sauce_location.js', 'jquery_handle'); ?>
```

And this for your special_sauce script.

```
 <script>
 ( function ($) {
 $('document').ready(function () {
 $('.carousel_container').each( function(i,obj) {
     obj.flexslider();
 });
 });
 })(jQuery);
 </script>
```

Haven't tested this whatsoever but I feel like it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it would be best to not have your function declaration inside the loop, but if you can't then this should work...

```
<?php
if(function_exists('your_function') == false) {
    function your_function() {
        echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');
?>
```